# Get min / max grouped by two columns

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables

Parts table:

```
id | part_id | group_id
 1 |         |        1
 2 |       1 |        1
 3 |         |        1
 4 |         |        2
```

Each part related to group and can be related to another part (analog)

Offers table:

```
offer_id | part_id | quantity
       1 |       1 |        1
       2 |       2 |        2
       3 |       2 |        3
       4 |       3 |        4
       5 |       4 |        5
```

Each offer related to part

I need to get best offers grouped by part or its related part ordered by lowest / highest quantity.

For group_id 1, when ordered ASC result should be

```
offer_id | part_id | quantity
       1 |       1 |        1
       4 |       3 |        4
```

When ordered DESC result should be

```
offer_id | part_id | quantity
       4 |       3 |        4
       3 |       2 |        3
```

I tried this query

```
SELECT 
         pi.offer_id, 
         pi.part_id,
         ( SELECT   pps.quantity
           FROM     offers AS pps
           WHERE    pps.offer_id = pi.offer_id
           ORDER BY pps.quantity asc
           LIMIT    1
         ) AS q
FROM offers AS pi
JOIN parts p ON p.id = pi.part_id
WHERE p.group_id = 1
GROUP BY part_id
ORDER BY q asc
```

Result:

```
offer_id | part_id | q
       1 |       1 | 1
       2 |       2 | 2
       4 |       3 | 4
```

It does not group parts and related parts (1 and 2) and returns 3 rows instead of two. How do i fix it?

UPDATE

Is it possible  if i change parts table data to this?

```
id | part_id | group_id
 1 |       1 |        1
 2 |       1 |        1
 3 |       3 |        1
 4 |       4 |        2
```

I also tried this query but it doesnt group by part_id too

```
SELECT a.id, a.part_id, a.quantity, p.part_id AS pid
FROM   supplier_offers a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT   part_id, Min(quantity) AS qty
    FROM     supplier_offers
    GROUP BY part_id
) b ON a.part_id = b.part_id AND a.quantity = b.qty
JOIN parts p ON p.id = a.part_id
WHERE p.cross_group_uuid = '78242c22-c113-4258-806c-936de014ba10'
ORDER BY a.quantity ASC
```

[Result from real db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mWyE.png)

UPDATE 2

It seems only way is to save part part_id in offers table and group by it

Comment: How can the result set be different when ordering `DESC` vs `ASC`? Why isn't it just the same rows in a different order?

Comment: @Nick not same because when asc order i choose offer with lowest quantity, when desc - highest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that this is possible, because only with as ordering you can't achieve this.
As you can see in the fiddle example you have also to add  a **and p.part_id is NULL**

> ```
> CREATE TABLE offers
>     (`offer_id` int, `part_id` int, `quantity` int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO offers
>     (`offer_id`, `part_id`, `quantity`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 1, 1),
>     (2, 2, 2),
>     (3, 2, 3),
>     (4, 3, 4),
>     (5, 4, 5)
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE parts
>     (`id` int, `part_id` int, `group_id` int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO parts
>     (`id`, `part_id`, `group_id`)
> VALUES
>     (1, NULL, 1),
>     (2, 1, 1),
>     (3, NULL, 1),
>     (4, NULL, 2)
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>   o.offer_id,o.part_id, o.quantity
> FROM offers o
> inner JOIN parts p 
> ON p.id = o.part_id
> WHERE group_id = 1 and p.part_id is NULL
> ```
>
> ```
> offer_id | part_id | quantity
> -------: | ------: | -------:
>        1 |       1 |        1
>        4 |       3 |        4
> ```

> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM
> (SELECT 
>   o.offer_id,o.part_id, o.quantity
> FROM offers o
> inner JOIN parts p 
> ON p.id = o.part_id
> WHERE group_id = 1
> ORDER  by quantity
> LIMIT 1) t1
> union ALL
> (SELECT 
>   o.offer_id,o.part_id, o.quantity
> FROM offers o
> inner JOIN parts p 
> ON p.id = o.part_id
> WHERE group_id = 1
> ORDER  by quantity DESC
> LIMIT 1)
> ```
>
> ```
> offer_id | part_id | quantity
> -------: | ------: | -------:
>        1 |       1 |        1
>        4 |       3 |        4
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>   o.offer_id,o.part_id, o.quantity
> FROM offers o
> inner JOIN parts p 
> ON p.id = o.part_id
> WHERE group_id = 1
> ORDER BY o.offer_ID DESC
> LIMIT 2
> ```
>
> ```
> offer_id | part_id | quantity
> -------: | ------: | -------:
>        4 |       3 |        4
>        3 |       2 |        3
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>   o.offer_id,o.part_id, o.quantity
> FROM offers o
> inner JOIN parts p 
> ON p.id = o.part_id
> WHERE group_id = 1 and p.part_id is NULL
> ORDER BY o.offer_ID ASC
> LIMIT 2
> ```
>
> ```
> offer_id | part_id | quantity
> -------: | ------: | -------:
>        1 |       1 |        1
>        4 |       3 |        4
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>          MIN(pi.offer_id), 
>          pi.part_id,
>         MIN( ( SELECT   pps.quantity
>            FROM     offers AS pps
>            WHERE    pps.offer_id = pi.offer_id
>            ORDER BY pps.quantity DESC
>            LIMIT    1
>          )) AS q
> FROM offers AS pi
> JOIN parts p ON p.id = pi.part_id
> WHERE p.group_id = 1 and p.part_id IS  NULL
> GROUP BY part_id
> ORDER BY q asc
> ```
>
> ```
> MIN(pi.offer_id) | part_id |  q
> ---------------: | ------: | -:
>                1 |       1 |  1
>                4 |       3 |  4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d391cc39dce17f1fc1b9ecaab5172ff3)*

Comment: i cant add p.part_id IS NULL because i need best offer between part 1 and 2 (since 2 related 1)

Comment: Like i said i can't see a solution for your problem because i can receive the min and max by sorting an dtaking the lowest and the higest, but i cant see that in case of 2 and 3 they are not the max and min of anything.